# Assign elements to clusters with constraints on element's properties - Optimization

Tags: optimization, cluster-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, constraint-programming

I have created 10 clusters based on latitude and longitude of multiple stores. I have the centroid lat longs of these clusters. Now I need to assign 70 sales reps to these stores. I want to achieve the following

1. the sum of distances of the stores from the centroid of a cluster should be minimized

with the constraints

1. Each store should be visited for a definite no of hours. the sum should not exceed 50 hours for any cluster
2. each store is either high priority or low priority. there should be a capping of 3 High priority stores in each cluster

I don't know where to start

Comment: Show what you've done so far. There is nothing reproducible here

Answer (score 0):

Define your cluster centroids as `c`, stores `s`, distance (centroid-store) as `d[c,s]`, hours per store as `h[s]`, priority per store `p[s]=1` if high, `p[s]=0` otherwise.

Define binary variables `z[c,s]=1` if store `s` is assigned to cluster/centroid `c`, 0 otherwise, integer variables `0 <= x[s]` is # of reps assigned to a store.

Constraints
`sum(x[s] over s) = 70`
`sum(h[s]z[c,s] over s) <= 50` for all c
`sum(p[s]z[s,c] over s) <= 3` for all c
`sum(z[s,c] over c) = 1` for all s:

Obj min `sum(d[s,c]z[s,c] over s, c)`

Need some more information regarding sales rep `x`, otherwise don't see any other meaningful role for `x`.